# Responsive fancybox iframe form with no scrollbars

Tags: fancybox

http://jsfiddle.net/work77/fb61a6za/ contains a fancybox link that opens up http://jsfiddle.net/work77/9eypabj6/ in an iframe.

The Iframe content consists of a random image (of varying unpredictable size) with a form beneath it. I'm trying to load that iframe in a fancybox window that is responsive onload and when resized, has no scrollbars ever and the aspect ratio is always preserved. I've tried all different combinations of fancybox properties ( hxxp://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) but nothing seems to work. I'm now just randomly shooting in the dark. Any Suggestions?

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    closeEffect: 'elastic',
    prevEffect: 'fade',
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    fitToView: false, // 
    maxWidth: "90%", //  
    type: 'iframe',
    scrolling: 'no',
    iframe: {
        preload: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Not 100% sure how I got there, but `aspectRatio : true` helped.
Also I have used `fitToView: true`, not false.

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
 aspectRatio : true,
 modal : true,
 scrolling : 'no',
 width : 500,
 height : 250,
 autoSize : false,
 autoWidth: false,
 autoHeight: false,
 fitToView: true,
```

(etc)...

Comment: Thanks plugincontainer. I was finally able to get this to work as well. Can't remember what I did.